Example of a ring that is not -additive
I am trying to create an example of a ring that does not have the added  -additivity. Is this a good example?
$$ \mathcal R= \{A \in \mathbb R : \textrm {A is a finite subset of } \mathbb R \}$$
My reasoning is as follows:

the empty set is finite and a subset of the whole set, so is included
if two sets are included the difference between the two is by definition finite and as such included
any finite union of finite subsets is always finite so included

Am I correct in this argument?

The example looks good to me, but your arguments are inaccurate. There are many infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ apart from the whole set, including uncountable ones, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ itself. $\sigma$-additivity only implies countable unions, so the whole set is not necessarily included.

You are correct, this has been adjusted.
